# Do I have to synchronize the RPCs in this scenario?

Tags: java, gwt, asynchronous, rpc

Yesterday I realized that what I am doing could potentially be a problem if I am not synchronizing my async requests - the question is if I *really* have to.

Let's take the following scenario: I have a top-level view that passes a list of data `List<SomeObject>` down to its sub views. All sub-level presenter are going to work with that list of data by means of adding, removing and modifying items of that list.

Let's say that a user does something in the UI and then hits the "Save"-button on multiple sub-level view instances which will call `SubLevelPresenter.onSaveSomeObjectButtonClick()`. This will perform an RPC call which result will be added to the `List<Somebject>` list.

My assumption is that it is possible that if the user click two different save buttons that the data may arrive at the same time triggering `onSaveSomeObjectButtonClick()` simultaneously which will cause simultaneous access to `List<SomeObject>`.

Do I have to synchronize these actions by implementing a queue e.g. or am I safe due to some internal GWT/JavaScript magic I don't see here?

```
public class TopLevelPresenter {

    private List<SomeObject> someObjectList = new ArrayList<>();    
    private List<SubLevelPresenter> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    public void TopLevelPresenter(TopLevelModel topLevelModel, TopLevelView topLevelView) {

        this.topLevelModel = topLevelModel;
        this.topLevelView = topLevelView;

        for(int i = 0; i < topLevelModel.getNumOfSubViews(); i++) {

            // Pass the data
            SubLevelModel subLevelModel = new SubLevelModel(someObjectList);
            SubLevelView subLevelView = new SubLevelView();         
            SubLevelPresenter subLevelPresenter = new SubLevelPresenter(subLevelModel, subLevelView);
            cache.add(subLevelPresenter);
        }
    }
}

public class SubLevelModel() {

    private List<SomeObject> someObjectList;

    public SubLevelModel(List<SomeObject> someObjectList) {
        this.someObjectList = someObjectList;
    }

    public void addSomeObject(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObjectList.add(someObject);
    }

    public void removeSomeObject(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.someObjectList.remove(someObject);
    }
}

public class SubLevelPresenter() {

    private SomeServiceAsync someService = /* .. */;
    private SubLevelView subLevelView;  
    private SubLevelModel subLevelModel;

    public SubLevelPresenter(SubLevelModel subLevelModel, SubLevelView subLevelView) {
        this.subLevelView = subLevelView;
        this.subLevelModel = subLevelModel;
    }

    public void onSaveSomeObjectButtonClick() {

        SomeObject toSave = this.subLevelView.getSuggestionBox().getSelection();

        someService.saveSomeObject(toSave, new AsyncCallback<SomeObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("RPC to saveSomeObject() failed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SomeObject savedObject) {
                SubLevelPresenter.this.subLevelModel.addSomeObject(savedObject);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `synchronized` keyword is useless (and ignored by GWT) in client-side code, given that JavaScript is single-threaded. Even if RPC responses arrived at the exact same time, they'd be queued up in the JavaScript event loop and processed one after the other.

Note that there are bugs in browsers (namely [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1180005)) leading to race conditions, but they cannot be detected and/or worked-around as easily as dropping some `synchronized` (or equivalent) keyword in the code. Also note the [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1180005) is related to `alert()` and `confirm()`.

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought but I wasn't sure. So, let's say I'm *really* afraid of a race condition, would it make sense to build a queue that sends one request after another? As it seems that would thwn just be a work-around for Firefox.

Comment: That 'd just move the issue to the queue management. And throw in the balance: the probability and frequency there are 2 in-flight requests, the probability of a race condition in a buggy browser (note that we don't know whether there **is** such a browser, Firefox issue seems related to the blocking `alert()` and `confirm()`, so depends whether you use any of them), the impact on your code (incl. maintainability), the impact on performance (and perceived performance for the user), the consequences if that happens ("fix" for the user if he notices is just one refresh away)

Comment: Okay, got it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario it seems to be OK to have multiple instances place data in your list after a RPC. However, it might be a good solution to make use of a synchronized list here to queue simultaneous access.

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: …or a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But that only applies to code that runs in a JVM, not when compiled to JavaScript using GWT, because JavaScript.